# Python writing data on SQL from .csv files

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, format

I want to automatize the ETL process from `.csv` files into SQL Server.

First of all I have a issue with `.csv` files who have this structure (see the next line). As you can see I need to delete the first line and the last 4.

https://ibb.co/Z6rrbPY

I try using pandas and csv services from python, but I don't find the solution. I'm stuck in this part and is the beginning of what I'm trying to do

Let me know what can I do.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just because a file has commas in it doesn't make it a CSV file. What you have looks like someone just saved a screen grab from a terminal screen. If you want to automate your process you'll need something that generates data in a standard format before you can actually work with it.

Comment: The photo is only a picture of an example of the .csv file who im trying to automate the ETL process. The file actually is a .csv file who i extract from a repository directory.

Comment: Please refer to [RFC 410 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). Your example data is not a CSV file so don't expect any CSV libraries to read from it without error.

Comment: I completely understand you, but well the system provides me a file compressed on a .zip, inside this we have a file in format .csv like the example. Im not questioning if the file is in the right way, the only thing i need is automatize this file with this format because is the only way i have to take that information.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Can you provide a sample snippet of the CSV in your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65330842/flat-file-python-sql-automatize-process-etl-script?noredirect=1#comment115539972_65330842

Comment: @Ben you can check in the previous message